# Office 365 quota for OneDrive and Groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, quota, office-365-groups

Looking over the `Get-SPOTenant` output of our tenant, I see the property OneDriveStorageQuota. This sets the quota for all OneDrive for Business users, no big deal. It is set to 1TB and we are fine with that.

Does this also affect Office Groups? I'm not in a position to test so I'm asking here.

I can make the logical leaps that an Office Group is a OneDrive site, therefore it would take this value, and for all intents and purposes, this is what we see when examining the Unified group via PowerShell. We're fine with 1TB personal spaces as those don't count against the pooled tenant storage and would like to enforce reasonable storage quotas on Groups when they are created.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-PowerShell-to-manage-Office-365-Groups-Admin-help-aeb669aa-1770-4537-9de2-a82ac11b0540. Checked this ?

Comment: I can already set the quotas after they are created. I want them to start with a lower base quota that we can increase over time instead of having the potential for a new group to consume all our pooled storage before we catch it. I'm wondering if this tenant property is tied to both Groups and OD4B. If they are tied, then we need to figure out how we will provision groups or get a uservoice going to allow for a separate property to set base group quota.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the quota for a group?  I may be able to test in my environment.

Comment: it is just a simple get-sposite -identity "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/group"